# Как добавить объекты в Scroll View из скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как добавить объекты в Scroll View из скрипта который висит на этом скроле?

```
Instantiate(object, transform);
```

Добавляет его в потомки, как добавить в `Viewport/Content` не смог найти, при запуске сцены и ручном добавлении скролл не расширяется, тоесть до конца не пролистать. Эта проблема отпадет с правильным вносом элементов в `Content`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут у вас целых два вопроса в одном. Давайте начнём с первого. Добавить чайлдом для контента *Scroll View* есть два способа:
**1.** Создаёте публичное поле *Transform _content* у нужного скрипта, перетаскиваете в это поле объект *Content* (который чайлд *Scroll View*). Теперь вызывая *Instantiate(object, _content);* вы будете создавать объекты, родителем которых является *Content*;
**2**. Если у вас уже есть ссылка на *Scroll View* можно получить его контент прямо из него с помощью поля *.content*. Т.е. ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
Scroll View _scroll;

void Generate()
{
    var content = _scroll.content;
    var targetTransform = content.transform;
    Instantiate(object, targetTransform);
}
```

Однако, это не решит вашей второй проблемы. Т.к. изначально контент у *Scroll View* статичен и не умеет перестраиваться. В этом вам поможет компонент *Content Size Fitter*. Его нужно вешать на объект *Content*, с его трансформацией он и будет работать.

Подробнее об использовании почитайте в документации или поищите в интернете ролики о применении (Google любезно подсказал, что такие есть).
[Документация по Content Size Fitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html)

Comment: Я размещал обьекты в скроле через `object.transform.position` они вставали как надо, после использования `Content Size Filter`  все элементы в один столбец, что можно сделать с этим?

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров, size filter только так и может изменять размер. Ему для работы нужна layout group - это она отвечает за выстраивание объектов в столбец (есть вертикальная, горизонтальная и сетка, у вас, видимо вертикальная на Content висит). Если вы хотите размещать объекты руками, то вам придётся пересчитывать вручную и размеры

Comment: Это оказалось не такой сложной задачей как мне показалось, буквально в пару строк) Но вот на что я совсем не смог найти ответа это добавить в наследники к изображению изображение.. Вам эта тайна ведома?)

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров, не совсем понял условия. Вы в том же методе, где создаёте объект в Content хотите ещё этому же объекту добавить в чайлды картинку? Метод Instantiate возвращает только что созданный объект. Т.е. если написать var obj = Instantiate(тут ваши параметры), то obj - будет ссылкой на только что созданный объект. Тогда вам достаточно сделать ещё один Instantiate, только в качестве родительской трансформации использовать уже трансформ только что созданного объекта (obj.transform)

Comment: Да, но `Instantiate` возвращает тип `Image` и на нем уже никак не использовать `Instantiate` так как второй параметр нужен `Transform`

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров, так ведь у любого класса, который наследуется от Component есть ссылка на трансформацию объекта, на котором этот компонент висит. Т.е. вы можете делать вот так: var obj = Instantiate(...); var targetTransfrom = obj.transfrom;

Comment: да, спасибо. Уже сделал но вот так `Transfor tr = obj.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();` такой способ нормальное решение?

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров, этот способ - вызов метода и поиск по объекту компонента "Transfrom". Нет смысла это делать, если трансформация уже найдена и захеширована, а на неё есть ссылка через .transform - вопрос производительности) да и кода меньше